# Tags on the Users page get truncated when they are too long

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

When the tags are too long, they overflow and the result is as in the image below.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Luckily this handsome dudes avatar got undamaged. You had that lying around somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rare cases where this happens, it's supposed to - we don't want them making the page extremely long when added up.